# desired route display in browser URL

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing, angular2-routing

I have routings like this in my main module routing.

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../HR/human-resources.module').then(m => m.HumanResourcesModule),
            }
        ]
    }];
```

and in the human-resources-routing.module.ts I have routings like this.

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: QuestionGroupComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'reports',
                component: DatePeriodComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'states',
                component: StateWithTopPersonnelComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'personnel',
                component: StatePersonnelComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'personnel-detail',
                component: PersonnelDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    }];
```

For example now when I want to go to DatePeriodComponent I have a URL like this *http://localhost:4200/home/reports* but something which I want to show is a bit different.
I want to show the URL like this *http://localhost:4200/reports* without home for all of my routs. How can I omit that or prevent to show in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was the simplest way I've ever seen and I'm the angriest person in the whole world now...
I did it just like this by setting an empty string to load the default module and component. I considered the dashboard module as my default module and dashboard component as my default component. Now when the app comes up I can see this URL *http://localhost:4200*

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'HR',
                loadChildren: () => import('../HR/human-resources.module').then(m => m.HumanResourcesModule),
            },
        ]
    },
   
];
```

and in my dashboard module

```js
const routes: Routes =
    [
        {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a way to solve this is to use a custom `UrlSerializer`.

`DefaultUrlSerializer` is the default implementation of `UrlSerializer` and it's used, for instance, by [`Router.parseUrl()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1227) method:

```js
urlTree = this.urlSerializer.parse(url);
```

or when [setting the browser's URL](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1338)(which might be what you need for your problem):

```js
private setBrowserUrl(
      url: UrlTree, replaceUrl: boolean, id: number, state?: {[key: string]: any}) {
    const path = this.urlSerializer.serialize(url);
    state = state || {};
    if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo(path) || replaceUrl) {
      // TODO(jasonaden): Remove first `navigationId` and rely on `ng` namespace.
      this.location.replaceState(path, '', {...state, navigationId: id});
    } else {
      this.location.go(path, '', {...state, navigationId: id});
    }
  }
```

A URL is a serialized version of a `UrlTree`. As a result, a `UrlTree` is the deserialized version of a URL. The `DefaultUrlSerializer` uses a `UrlParser` to deserialize a URL string:

```js
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    const p = new UrlParser(url);
    return new UrlTree(p.parseRootSegment(), p.parseQueryParams(), p.parseFragment());
  }
```

So what you could do to solve this problem is to provide a custom implementation of `UrlSerializer`:

```js
// In `providers` array
{ provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomImplOfUrlSerializer },
```

A possible(and basic) implementation could be to use alter the returned value of `DefaultUrlSerializer.serialize(urlTree)` in `CustomImplOfUrlSerializer.serialize(urlTree)`, by replacing `/home` with `''`:

```js
class CustomImplOfUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  serialize (urlTree: UrlTree): string {
    const raw = (new DefaultUrlSerializer()).serialize(urlTree);

    return raw.replace('/home', '')
  }
}
```

Also, if you'd like to read more about `UrlTree` and why it is useful, I'd recommend checking out [this article](https://andreigatej.dev/blog/angular-router-urlree).

Comment: It seems logical but I'm confused about how and where to use. @Andrei Gătej

Comment: @siavashbashiri I think you don't have to do more than defining `CustomImplOfUrlSerializer` and providing it using `{ provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomImplOfUrlSerializer },`. If you could create a StackBlitz demo, I'd be glad to set it up then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It works but I have a problem now , when I refresh the page using browser refresh button it doesn't work because can't find the route which home is removed from that

Comment: @siavashbashiri I think you'll have to add some logic in the `CustomUrlSerializer.parse()` method. AFAIK, this is called at the beginning of a route navigation.